# How to save value of variable from one function call and use it to the next function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, ros

I am implementing a cartesian control of a robotic manipulator and below you can see the function which produces the joint velocities in order to perform the control:

```
def cartesian_control(joint_transforms, b_T_ee_current, b_T_ee_desired,
                      red_control, q_current, q0_desired):
    num_joints = len(joint_transforms)
    dq = numpy.zeros(num_joints)
    
    ee_current_T_b = tf.transformations.inverse_matrix(b_T_ee_current)    
    current_T_desired = numpy.dot(ee_current_T_b, b_T_ee_desired)    
    current_P_desired = tf.transformations.translation_from_matrix(current_T_desired)    
    current_R_desired = current_T_desired[:3,:3]    
    angle, axis = rotation_from_matrix(current_T_desired)
    rot_movement = numpy.dot(angle,axis)
    desired_R_current = tf.transformations.inverse_matrix(current_R_desired)
    
    delta_X = numpy.append(current_P_desired, rot_movement)
    
    # Proportional - Derivative Controller 
    Kp = 5 # Proportional Gain
    Kd = 1 # Derivative Gain
    delta_delta_X = (delta_X - delta_X_prev)/0.01
    
    x_dot = Kp*delta_X + Kd*delta_delta_X
    
    # Scale translational and angular velocities for smoothness    
    for i in range(3):
        if x_dot[i] > 1:
            x_dot[i] = 1
            
    for i in range(3,1,5):
        if x_dot[i] > 0.1:
            x_dot[i] = 0.1
    
    J = numpy.empty((6,0))
    V = numpy.zeros((6,6))
    
    for i in range(num_joints):
        
        b_T_joint = joint_transforms[i]        
        ee_T_joint = numpy.dot(ee_current_T_b, b_T_joint)        
        joint_T_ee = tf.transformations.inverse_matrix(ee_T_joint)        
        ee_R_joint = rotation_matrix(ee_T_joint)        
        joint_P_ee = tf.transformations.translation_from_matrix(joint_T_ee)        
        joint_skew_matrix = S_matrix(joint_P_ee)        
        V[:3,:3] = ee_R_joint
        V[3:6,3:6] = ee_R_joint
        V[:3, 3:6] = numpy.dot(-ee_R_joint, joint_skew_matrix)
        
        J = numpy.column_stack((J, V[:,5]))
        
    J_pseudoinv = numpy.linalg.pinv(J, rcond=0.01)
    dq = numpy.dot(J_pseudoinv, x_dot)
    
    # Scale joint velocities
    for i in range(len(dq)):
        
        if dq[i] > 0.1:
            dq[i] = 0.1

    return dq
```

The above function works perfectly in case I implement just a proportional controller, which means that in case of `x_dot = Kp*delta_X + Kd*delta_delta_X1` I have only `x_dot = Kp*delta_X`. However, I would like also to implement a proportional derivative controller but my problem is how to obtain the `delta_X_prev` variable. This means that I need to find a way of saving the value of the variable `delta_X` of one function call and use it at the function call. Did some search and I found that the `multiprocessing` python module would help but really haven't understood the whole concept of it. Is there any other simpler way it order to do that?

Comment: Have you considered splitting this into *multiple* functions? Memoization/caching (see ``functools``) could help if you need to re-use the result of one function often (and if it is stable). In general, if your code snippet is one function but needs a scrollbar, this is a good sign you actually have several functions welded together.

Comment: Well, this function I have attached is part of larger project (course assignment) and the structure has to stay the same. So it is not easy to ruin the structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "the structure has to stay the same"? Surely *some* modifications must be possible, since you are asking how to re-use one variable – which requires modifications/refactoring.

Comment: Yes, maybe add a function in order to achieve what I want with the variable call but all the other computations have to be implemented inside the current function.